# What is the best way to generate & print out data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I want print out 1 mil user record from database to paper.

The output format will be something like this.

```
No       Name    Address   Phone     Class  Teacher
----------------------------------------------------
1        John    123-etc   3214124   5      Miku
2        L.Gaga  123-etc   3214124   9      Koru
..
..
..
..
10000000 Puke    123123    3214124   2      Goku
```

What is the best method to print out this data without adding any limit to mysql query?

Comment: Do you know the worst method?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641

Comment: @zerkms That is an interesting question.

Comment: You want to print a million lines on paper? I'd suggest a very small font size and multiple pages/sheet. Oh, and don't let Greenpeace know about this. :)

Comment: which type of database? print to paper, browser, flat file? why no limits? ajaxing for the next N records is probably best, but that typically uses limits.

Comment: without adding limit? why would not?

Comment: @amosrivera he will print it in a tarpaulin paper

Comment: Thanks guy for your comments. There have a trick to add limit to mysql query using timer. let's say every 5 or 10  minutes query will limit to `LIMIT 0,100` then `LIMIT 100,200`until 1 million row.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do in such a case, is using a tool like Navicat to write a query that gives me exactly the columns I need, ordered in the way I need them, and then use the export function of the tool to save the result in an Excel file.

That way I get all the Excel (or OpenOffice, for that matter) options for printing, including scaling to get as much records on one page as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could query as normal and use PHP to write the results to a CSV file for further formatting, printing, etc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

I don't think 1 million rows will be too much, but it will depend on your hardware (memory), environment (php timeouts), and the actual data. The paper itself might be a problem, though.